# WildFly Elytron for Management authentication with multiple Realms

Tags: wildfly, elytron

I am trying to configure WildFly Elytron to allow authentication on the Management Interface using two different Realms with a fallback.

For the example I have a `ManagementRealm` and a `MyLDAPRealm` that I want to use. If the user is recognized in the `ManagementRealm`, the user should have access to the management interface. If not, I want to try the `MyLDAPRealm`. If the user is recognized this time, he should have access to the management interface. If not, it should fail. A *simple* fallback.

I updated the `standalone.xml` configuration to use Elytron but it is currently not working and the documentation is not helping as much as hoped. Currently I have the following configuration bits.

The management interface is using the authentication factory that I want to configure:

```
<management-interfaces>
    <http-interface http-authentication-factory="management-http-authentication" ssl-context="localhostSslContext">
      <http-upgrade enabled="true" sasl-authentication-factory="management-sasl-authentication"/>
      <socket-binding http="management-http" https="management-https"/>
    </http-interface>
</management-interfaces>
```

The authentication factory links to the Management Domain that I will update:

```
<http-authentication-factory name="management-http-authentication" security-domain="ManagementDomain" http-server-mechanism-factory="global">
    <mechanism-configuration>
        <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST">
            <mechanism-realm realm-name="Management and LDAP"/>
        </mechanism>
    </mechanism-configuration>
</http-authentication-factory>
```

And the Management Domain I updated to include an additional Realm:

```
<security-domain name="ManagementDomain" default-realm="ManagementRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
  <realm name="ManagementRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
  <realm name="MyLDAPRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
  <realm name="local" role-mapper="super-user-mapper"/>
</security-domain>
```

With this configuration, the user is authenticated and allowed in if it is in the `ManagementRealm` but not if it is in the `MyLDAPRealm`.

Is this configuration possible or am I missing something in the Elytron chain ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try a **failover-realm** like here:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/managing-failover-and-distributed-realms-in-elytron